# Prime Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Let $ p = 4n + 1$ cousin. Prove that p$ | n ^ n - 1$

The only thing I developed was:

$1 = n ^ n (mod p)$

$1 = n (mod p)$

$4 = 4n (mod p)$

Maybe it has to do with Fermat's cousins